# Why does Keras ImageDataGenerator throwing Memory Error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am building a simple "Cat vs Dog Classifier" in Keras. While fitting the `ImageDataGenerator` I am getting `MemoryError`. My Code looks like this:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

image_gen = ImageDataGenerator(shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True) 

image_gen.fit(X)
```

X has a shape of `(25000,150,150,3)`

What am I doing wrong or how to fix this?

I have already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49458905/memory-error-when-using-keras-imagedatagenerator) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55291658/memory-error-in-multi-inputs-model-when-using-keras-imagedatagenerator).

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-2fd88662a693> in <module>
----> 1 image_gen.fit(X)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py in fit(self, x, augment, rounds, seed)
    943             np.random.seed(seed)
    944 
--> 945         x = np.copy(x)
    946         if augment:
    947             ax = np.zeros(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in copy(a, order)
    790 
    791     """
--> 792     return array(a, order=order, copy=True)
    793 
    794 # Basic operations

MemoryError:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using data augmentation in the generator, which essentially triples the number of images you have. Most likely your computer cannot handle 75k images in memory (due to low RAM especially GPU RAM). Your choices are either to reduce the image sizes, reduce the augmentation, or have the data-generator read your images from folders without storing them in memory (by batch).

As shown [here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) it will look like this:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/validation',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')

# Change to match your problem
model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=2000,
        epochs=50,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=800)
```

Comment: As far as I Understand  `flow_from_directory() ` requires data to be in class-wise separate folder. Does this also work when data of different classes are in same folder ?

Comment: @mmrbulbul it will work but will treat them as the same class, so your results will be poor. Using `flow_from_directory()` does require more data pre-processing but it is worth it if you don't want to run into memory related issues.

Comment: Then I should better separate the data first and use `flow_from_directory() `. Thank you @Ibragile

Comment: @mmrbulbul Exactly, please consider accepting my answer by clicking the "checkmark" if you found it useful.